# If without else - Python lists

Tags: python, list

I know that the following code is valid:

```
list = [1 , 2 if 1==1 else 0, 3]
```

but how can I omit the list insertion if the if expression (1==1 in this case) returns false?

I mean, I don't want to insert any value (including 'None', '[]') if the expression is not valid.

I tried something like this

```
list = [1 , 2 if 1==1, 3]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that what you have there is not a list comprehension, it's just a plain list.

Comment: How can you complete the assignment without an `else` case? Also, this has nothing to do with lists.

Comment: @agconti While it's true this has nothing to do with lists exactly, it's a bit esoteric for a newbie to grasp why not.  Until you really get your head around declaring literals and recognizing order of execution, saying "this has nothing to do with lists" really only begs the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To optionally include an item in a list, you'll have to break the assignment into several parts:

```
l = [1] + ([2] if 1 else []) + [3]
```

(The parentheses might be optional, but they can't hurt; I'm not sure what precedence the conditional expression has.)

This is short way of writing

```
if 1:
    l = [1] + [2] + [3]  # Which is just [1,2,3]
else:
    l = [1] + [] + [3]   # Which is just [1,3]
```

Any element specified in a list literal must exist; there is no way to write a possibly non-existent item in Python.

---

If you are familiar with Perl, something similar *is* possible, but only because Perl has very different semantics.

Compare the assignment

```
@list = (1, 0 ? 2 : (), 3)
```

which will produce the list `(1, 3)` because `(1, (), 3)` is interpreted as the concatenation of 3 lists `(1,), (), and (3,)`, in part because you cannot nest lists inside other lists. On the other hand

```
@list = (1, 1 ? 2 : (), 3)
```

produces the list `(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, since it actually solves the problem. +1

Answer (score 11):

You can't in that usage, because you're defining a literal list with three values.  By putting two commas and three expressions between the brackets, you have committed yourself to providing three elements in the list.  There is no way to have an expression that "disappears" without evaluating to something.

In an actual list *comprehension*, you can do it by putting the `if` in the `for` clause rather than in the target expression:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [a if a != 3 else 'three' for a in x]
[1, 2, 'three', 4]
>>> [a for a in x if a != 3]
[1, 2, 4]
```

The first comprehension uses a conditional expression `a if a != 3 else 'three'`, which must have both `if` and `else` parts because an expression must evaluate to some value. The second comprehension uses `if a !=3` because that is part of the list comprehension syntax; it is not part of a conditional expression and in this case cannot contain an `else`. Its job is to simply put a restriction on which values from `x` are assigned to `a`, rather than evaluating to a value itself.

Comment: Note that this doesn't solve the OP's problem of applying a conditional to the existence of a *single* element of the list. This applies the `a != 3` condition to the entire list. While the information in this answer is correct, it's not exactly relevant.

Comment: It's quite relevant, as the first sentence explains that you can't have an element that can "disappear" as the result of a failed test.

Comment: @chepner My mistake, I should have been more specific, the information in the second part of the answer is irrelevant.